# how to Scroll down a list in javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll, puppeteer

So I'm doing a project with puppeteer and I have a div with a list of some elements (the list is the followers on my profile of Instagram), and I want to automatically scroll down to the bottom of that list with JavaScript.

The thing is that as I scroll down to the the bottom of the list new elements keep appearing. So if I have 200 followers for instance I have to scroll down until no new followers keep appearing.

I tried that so far, but it doesn't get me anywhere

```javascript
var element = document.querySelector('.jSC57  ._6xe7A');
element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
```

How can I code that with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

This function does what you're looking for but for the browser window, it should work for you if the new elements that keep appearing increases the window size

```
async function scrollToBottomOfWindow(page) {
        const distance = 50; // should be less than or equal to window.innerHeight
        const delay = 500; // giving delay allows new elements in the list to load
        while (await page.evaluate(() => document.scrollingElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight < document.scrollingElement.scrollHeight)) {
          await page.evaluate((y) => { document.scrollingElement.scrollBy(0, y); }, distance);
          await page.waitFor(delay);
        }
}
```

On the opposite, this one should solve your problem if the new appearing elements don't increase the window size, just the element's inner height

```
async function scrollToBottomOfElement(page, element) {
    const distance = 50;
    const delay = 500;
    while (await page.evaluate(() => element.scrollTop < element.scrollHeight)) {
      await page.evaluate((y) => { element.scrollingElement.scrollBy(0, y); }, distance);
      await page.waitFor(delay);
    }
}
```

Comment: the new elements doesnt increase the windoww size, neither the elements inner height. As you scroll down new elements keep appearing , the only thing that is increasing is the scroll bar.